# Postfix not receiving external mail on Azure virtual machine

Tags: postfix, azure, mx-record

I am trying to configure Postfix to receive emails. I am finding pieces to the puzzle online, but no combination of things seem to work. Emails never show up.

Here is my current setup:

- Ubuntu VM running in Azure with Postfix installed. I can send email
  locally on the server to itself.
- Purchased a domain from a registrar and configured it to point at a DNS Zone setup in Azure.
- Created A and MX records in this DNS Zone. These records have propagated.

Below is my DNS Zone: (The IP address is the public IP address of my Azure virtual machine)

[image]

One of the [links](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c67357ff-9e43-4370-868f-7fd1f69f74ec/mx-dns-to-send-and-receive-emails?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork) I found said that my MX record should point to myVMNAME.cloudapp.net. I tried this, but when I looked up the MX record with MX Toolbox showed "No A Record".

I am not sure where to go from here. Is there something that needs to be changed in the Postfix main.cf file? Am I missing a DNS entry somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Does the FQDN in the MX record resolve to an IP address?  What happens when you use nslookup on the address in the MX record?

Also, Azure blocks outbound port 25 by default (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity)

Comment: My .org domain resolves to an IP address. The VMNAME.cloudapp.net does not. I have my MX record pointing to my .org domain. I am aware of the outbound on port 25 issue, but in this scenario I am trying to receive email via port 587. I have verified this port is open via telnet.

Answer (score -1):

There is a new article from Microsoft:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity

Salut!
J.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/517147)

Comment: In the Microsoft article they only talk about OUTGOING smtp mail. This has nothing to do with the original question. Easy mistake to make, but it's not very helpful.